# animate their serious faces/expressions/look

Tags: word-choice

I've made up three versions of the example below.

(1) Some of the people I know always seem emotionless. However, my funny gestures can **animate their serious faces.**

(2) Some of the people I know always seem emotionless. However, my funny gestures can **animate their serious expressions.**

(3) Some of the people I know always seem emotionless. However, my funny gestures can **animate their serious look.**

Which noun goes well with "animate": serious faces/expression/look?

Comment: (1) animate their faces.